# How to Create A Merged Array from 3 Arrays with LINQ which is not zipped but based on Content Equality

Tags: c#, linq

I have three Arrays which should be merged into one result via Linq:

```
int?[] list1 = {0,1,2,3,4};
int?[] list2 = {2,3,4,5};
int?[] list3 = {3,4};
```

Result:

```
var result=
{
    (0,null,null),
    (1,null,null),
    (2,2,null),
    (3,3,3),
    (4,4,4),
    (null,5,null)
}
```

Comment: And what´s your problem? What have yo tried? We´re not doing your work. Anyway It´s hard to understand the logic behind.How should the lists be merged?

Comment: The thing is I dont know how to start. I just need a quick hint which Method/Linq Statement I can use

Comment: Just type as you would do it by hand. *Afterwards* search for simpilifications or whatever. As soon as you wrote which steps are needed - e.g. by some psueodcode - the actual code-writing becomes quite easy.

Comment: @rudimenter: start with explaining your logic and fixing the unnecessary compile errors in your sample lists

Comment: You want to create triplets based on all existing values where each triplets holds the common values sort of like umm? What _for_? What exactly are you trying to _achieve_?

Comment: Maybe GroupJoin will do the trick. Just need to figure out how exactly.

Comment: maybe the intersect method could be usefull
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/linq-expect-intersect-and-union-method-operator-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: @LocEngineer Exactly like that. A Triplet with all common values.

Comment: @rudimenter: it not even clear what type `result` is. You really think using `var` is helpful to explain your desired result? Or you don't know yourself what you need?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thats not important. I am just learning about the LINQ and how to write it. It could be a Tuple. The focus is on the LINQ query.

Comment: Then you should *definitly* have some working code for the actual logic. *Afterwards* try to do it with linq. Don´t overcomplicate things by learning complicate linq-stuff, when you don´t even have an idea what to *query* (that´s what the q in LINQ stands for). Have a look at some linq-examples and the docs instead.

Comment: @rudimenter: LINQ is not the best tool if you have to create jagged arrays which seems to be the case here. Normally a loop is faster and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by defining our input in a little more generic terms: a list of a list of integers. Since we don't need to modify these collections, we'll use the simplest interface that gives us what we need, `IEnumerable<T>`. That means our input is going to be: `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int?>>`. Our output is going to be the same.

So now, let's define a prototype for the method that will do the work:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int?>> Merge(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int?>> source) { //... }
```

Immediately I've noticed something: we don't really need to use `int?` since all we care about is checking equality, and all types support that, so we can make this method generic, and support any type:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Merge<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source) { //... }
```

Now let's start with the implementation, first we will need to compute every distinct value from all the lists:

```
source.SelectMany(x=>x).Distinct()
```

Now, for each of those values we need to return a collection with an item for each item in the original 'super list':

```
source.SelectMany(x=>x).Distinct().Select(x=>source.Select(y=> //...
```

So what do we need in that final Select lambda? We have x as each distinct integer (or technically `T`), and y as each original collection. We want the value x if the y collection contains x, otherwise, null (or to allow value types too, default(T). We can do that with a ternary:

```
source.SelectMany(x=>x).Distinct().Select(x=>source.Select(y=>y.Contains(x)?x:default(T)));
```

Putting it all together:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Merge<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source) 
{
    return source
        .SelectMany(x=>x)
        .Distinct()
        .Select(x=>source
            .Select(y=>y.Contains(x)?x:default(T)));
}
```

And you can call it like so:

```
int?[] list1 = {0,1,2,3,4};
int?[] list2 = {2,3,4,5};
int?[] list3 = {3,4};
var result = new []{ list1, list2, list3 }.Merge();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Select(t=>string.Join(",", t))));
```

Answer (score 0):

First put all your arrays into one:

```
var lists = new[] { list1, list2, list3 };
```

Now loop all possible numbers and check if check if they are contained in the appropriate arrays. If so, you can add that number to your result, otherwise add `null`:

```
var result = new List<List<int?>>();
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    result.Add(new List<int?>());
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        if(lists[j].Contains(i))
            result[i].Add(i);
        else
            result[i].Add(null);
    }
}
```

I suppose this is pretty straightforward. Doing this is linq will just overcomplicate things, looks ugly and is hard to debug and understand. I doubt it´s a good idea to do so.